# Трактовки русских слов у С. Алексеева

Tags: лингвистика

Почитал книги Сергея Алексеева. Очень интересно, но, признаться, его расшифровки истинного смысла русских слов показались мне, мягко говоря, притянутыми за уши. Я не ортодокс от науки и люблю новые и смелые теории, но тут... ощущение, что все это из серии так называемой "контактерской" информации, выдаваемой за правду.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто вообще основоположник этой, так сказать, теории. То есть, когда я о ней говорю, на кого ссылаться?
Спасибо

Comment: Уважаемый Тао. Книга, о которой вы упоминаете, возможна, знакома не всем участником форума( в том числе и мне). Не могли бы вы привести ссылку на книгу или привести хотя бы пару примеров из этой книге?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В печатном виде книгу не видела, кое-что читала в интернете, слушала:

http://www.liveinternet.ru/users/firefamer/post273228821

http://www.liveinternet.ru/users/3469412/post248616188

Как относиться, пока не знаю. Больше похоже на проповеди, чем на лингвистические исследования. Суть его идеи понятна: вернуть русскому слову его первоначальный смысл, магию слова до появления грамматики, изменения языка под иноземным влиянием (немецким большей частью). Какой смысл в этом - пока не понимаю, мы разговариваем на этом языке, том, каким он стал под влиянием жизни. Он хочет создать этимологический словарь доиндоевропейского периода, по-моему, это невозможно, будут домыслы и фантазии. Хотя мысль интересная, почитать можно, но ведь есть всякие "веды" и т.д., что-то научного у них ничего не наблюдается. Куда они нас заведут - неведомо.

Answer (score 2):

Никакого отношения к науке измышления Алексеева не имеют. Мне понравился его цикл "Сокровища валькирий", но нужно понимать, что это художественное произведение, а не научная работа. Так как книга, благодаря крепкому приключенческому сюжету и патриотичным рассуждениям о величии русского народа и его языка (именно у Алексеева Михаил Задорнов позаимствовал большинство из своих этимологических "открытий") попали на благодатную почву и сделали автора популяным, однако по сути все эти изыскания, не более чем научная фантастика.